# How to perform case-insensitive in array of arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of arrays. I need to set an array of arrays in a case-insensitive way. How to perform this?

I've got this array and I need to set it to lowercase.

```
   var criminals = [
        ["Paul White", "Roger Night, Peter Llong Jr."], 
        ["Roger Fedexer", "Rob Ford, Pete Lord, Roger McWire"],
        ["Paul White Jr.", null],
        ["Red Fortress", "Roger Rabbit, Ross Winter"],
        ["Redford Fort", "Red Strong, Red Fort"]
    ];
```

I've tried this

```
  var sorted = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < criminals.length; i++) {
        sorted.push(criminals[i].toLowerCase());

        console.log(sorted)
   }
```

But I got the following

```
TypeError: criminals[i].toLowerCase is not a function
```

Comment: [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a method of `String`.  You need to apply it to individual items.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to loop that inner array, also had to account for that null value, which is why we're doing that ternary check

```
criminals[i][t]?criminals[i][t].toLowerCase():criminals[i][t]
```

```js
var criminals = [
        ["Paul White", "Roger Night, Peter Llong Jr."], 
        ["Roger Fedexer", "Rob Ford, Pete Lord, Roger McWire"],
        ["Paul White Jr.", null],
        ["Red Fortress", "Roger Rabbit, Ross Winter"],
        ["Redford Fort", "Red Strong, Red Fort"]
    ];
    
    var sorted = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < criminals.length; i++) {
        var _inner = [];
        for(let t = 0; t < criminals[i].length; t++){
            _inner.push(criminals[i][t]?criminals[i][t].toLowerCase():criminals[i][t]);
        }
        sorted.push(_inner);
   } 
   console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much Kyle!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using map method :

```js
let criminals= ["Paul White", "Roger Night", "Peter Llong Jr."];
let sorted= criminals.map((item) => {
  return item.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let sorted = criminals.forEach(c => c[0].toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just did that but I got "undefined"

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the OP's question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.